# Peer-Reviewed Scholarly Works Questioning the Internal Unity of 2 Esdras 1-2

Tags: textual-criticism, apocrypha, resource-request, pseudepigrapha, 2esdras

Among the *King James Version* Apocrypha, there is a certain book, called [Second Esdras](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2_Esdras), which is found neither in the [Masoretic Text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masoretic_Text), nor in the [Greek Septuagint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Septuagint); its [first two](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?interface=print&version=NRSV&search=2_Esdras_1-2) and [last two](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?interface=print&version=NRSV&search=2_Esdras_15-16) chapters are independent sections, called the *Fifth and Sixth Books of Ezra*, while the middle portion, spanning from the third to the fourteenth chapter, forms what is usually labeled as *Fourth Ezra*.

Whilst researching various scholarly books and articles, *freely available online*, relating to the [textual criticism of 5 Ezra](http://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3718) (2 Esdras 1-2), I was somewhat surprised to discover that the work is usually perceived as forming a monolithic unit, being commonly regarded as an early Christian work. While distinctly and unequivocally Christian elements are indeed found within the text's present form, thus partially explaining the aforementioned view, what struck me as rather odd was that not even a single scholar, *from among the ones I had access to*, appeared particularly inclined to question, or cast as much as the tiniest shadow of doubt, on this seemingly universally accepted thesis; which only brings me to my question:

**Are there any peer-reviewed scholarly works, questioning the alleged internal unity of 5 Ezra (2 Esdras 1-2) ?**

*(After all, it could well be that either my Google skills are lacking, or that such works might not be freely available online).*

Comment: There are some valuable, first-pass references (that will lead to other references) in both 
  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esdras and  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2_Esdras#5_Ezra  The works by Metzger and Robinson are useful.

Comment: The Structure and Composition of 5 Ezra
- Theodore A. Bergren : https://www.jstor.org/stable/20700360

Comment: Fifth Ezra: The Text, Origin, and Early History (Septuagint and Cognate Studies Series, No 25) - Theodore A. Bergren : https://www.amazon.com/Fifth-Ezra-History-Septuagint-Cognate/dp/9990509387

Comment: “5 Ezra 2:10--14: Its Place in the Book’s Structure and in Christian Supersessionism.” Journal for the Study of the Pseudepigrapha 29.1 (2019) 54-76 : https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/full/10.1177/0951820719860655

Comment: @חִידָה: As far as I can tell, the provided links seem to affirm the text's unity, rather than question it.

Comment: Are you asking : Which scholars claim the text of [2 Esdras 1-2] can be validated by Sefer Ezra?

Comment: @חִידָה: No. I am asking whether there are credible scholars or researchers who do not subscribe to the opinion that 5 Ezra is the work of a single (early Christian) author.

Comment: @Dottard: [Robinson](http://archive.org/details/rulesoftyconius00tico/page/n253) also seems to affirm the text's unity, rather than call it into question, which is what I'm after.